# ping from docker container cannot reach outside hosts

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to ping from a docker container running along with other services controlled with docker-compose.
Basic requirement is to connect to external db servers, which is not working. To debug I tried to ping the external box, which as expected don't return. I can however ping the external box from vm host.

The `/etc/hosts` has entry as I have provided following line in docker-compose.yml

```
extra_hosts:
     - "externalhostname:10.40.154.27"
```

From docker inspect the following is the network details

```
"Networks": {
        "echo_service_default": {
            "IPAMConfig": null,
            "Links": null,
            "Aliases": [
                "python-interpreter",
                "3767f3a7ad80"
            ],
            "NetworkID": "10ca2ec9a1dbc3659cef91014c2c64c8df17e9d720350d1bdd198a53c6c0a946",
            "EndpointID": "c920443c34ff00ffefe2c669bc4b80e121c27d1b8ebc44fa9f5efb16e71561a4",
            "Gateway": "172.19.0.1",
            "IPAddress": "172.19.0.6",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:06",
            "DriverOpts": null
        }
```

`ifconfig` in host gives

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:b6ff:fe86:fb71  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:b6:86:fb:71  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 204  bytes 90455 (88.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5080  bytes 459752 (448.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The service entry from docker-compose.yml

```
  python-interpreter:
image: image name
hostname: python-interpreter
volumes:
 - /scratch/share:/var/python-interpreter/data:ro
 - shared:/var/shared
extra_hosts:
 - "externalhostname:10.40.154.27"
```

so the service is running with bridge network with no -p option

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: it is on linux el7. docker-compose 2

Comment: then it seems strange that it doesn't work. I have used the same setup many times. Can you make sure that the IP is correct? Also run `docker-compose down` and make sure the compose network is also removed. Then restart with docker-compose up and try again. let me know if that fixes it

Comment: restarting docker compose  does not work

Answer (score 1):

In the docker-compose.yml you shared, the python-interpreter service has a extra_hosts definition but not a network definition, you need to define a network, for example:

```
  python-interpreter:
image: image name
hostname: python-interpreter
volumes:
- /scratch/share:/var/python-interpreter/data:ro
- shared:/var/shared
networks:
  - backend
```

And define the network at the end of your docker-compose.yml :

```
    networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Thanks for responding , but I thought bridge is by default if i dont mention anything. It seems the same is what Mihai is saying.  do you mean i need to provide port forwarding with ports clause for the external ports i need to access? even for out bound ports? please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

it seems it is working now..
i changed to host mode

```
python-interpreter:
      image: ...
    hostname: ...
    **network_mode: host**
    volumes:
     ...
    extra_hosts:
     - "whf00aqw.in.oracle.com:10.40.154.27"
```

I believe (not sure.)because it was going to bridge , it was restricting network access to within host. Now that i have made it host , it is able to share host network and able to access.